# Do you need a Macbook Pro w touchID to test the authentication in your Swift app?

Tags: macos, xcode, touch-bar, touch-id, swift

I'm thinking of buying a MBP base model for Swift programming, and I know that Xcode has a simulator for the touch-bar, but do I need the one with actual touchID hardware if I want my app to require a biometrical login? or is there a way to debug and test it without needing it; same as the touchID with iOS?

So do I need the one with touch-bar and touchID for this purpose? And also will I need it in future?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need it to develop such applications. However you do need a Mac with Touch ID in order to completely test that feature. There’s no simulator in Xcode for macOS applications with Touch ID as such.

Usually it is not really necessary to actually test Touch ID though. It is a single line change to swap out Touch ID with local authentication so that you can test with passwords until you are satisfied that works, and then change it to Touch ID.

No one can know if you need this in the future. The future is, after all, still undecided.